# Match a Phrase if it includes all words from a list - regex

Tags: regex

I have phrases, as such:

```
computer keyboard
computer keyboard black
computer keyboard black mouse
```

I then have an array of words, but I only want to return the phrases when every word matches an entry in the array.

Here is an example array:

```
["keyboard","computer","black"]
```

I'd like to match 'computer keyboard', and 'computer keyboard black', but not 'computer keyboard black mouse', since mouse does not exist in the list of words.

Here's what I have so far:

```
(?=.*?(keyboard|computer|black)).*
```

The only problem is, obviously, this still matches for the 3rd phrase.  Is this possible using regular expressions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use `^(?:(?:keyboard|computer|black)(?: |$))+$` in multiline `m` mode...

This means:

`^ ... $` - match must be from start of line to end of line

`(?: ... )+` - group repeating one or more times

`(?:keyboard|computer|black)(?: |$)` - one of three words ending with a space or end of line

All groups are non-capturing `?:` because you need only a full phrases

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/d0dD0w/3

Comment: Thanks Sergey - works but now postgresql is complaining 'regular expression is too complex'